# How can I add a search layout to a change set for a standard object?

Tags: deployment, change-set, search-layout

Is it possible? I want to deploy a search layout of the standard object Account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For standard objects/standard fields (like picklists or revised labels)/search layouts, changesets aren't very useful -

Search Layouts are implicitly part of the SObject and you can't use changesets to move standard objects

I don't believe you can do what you are asking within changesets.  Note idea https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000HJ3kAAG

You can use Eclipse, Gearset, Force.com Migration Tool or other tools that exploit the Metadata API to move the search layouts if you deploy the standard Account object

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it [has been delivered](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000klzzAAA) but I can't figure out how to do it